# document.getElementById('button').click() working on my pc but not working on another pc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `DIV` when i click on it it will trigger a javascript to click on file upload button which was `display:none`. It works on my pc with Chrome, Firefox, Chromium. But I wonder why it does not work on my friend pc.

> Is it because the browser issue or what? Me and my friend using
>   different version of Ubuntu. Nothing happen when they click on the DIV

Here is my code

`<div onclick='uploadphoto()' title='Click to edit Profile Picture'></div>`

```
<form action="js/ajaxuploadprofile.php" method="post" name="sleeker" id="sleeker" enctype="multipart/form-data" style='display:none'>
    <input type="hidden" name="maxSize" value="2000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="maxW" value="700" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fullPath" value="images/profilepic/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="relPath" value="../images/profilepic/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="colorR" value="255" />
    <input type="hidden" name="colorG" value="255" />
    <input type="hidden" name="colorB" value="255" />
    <input type="hidden" name="maxH" value="700" />
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="filename" />
    <input type="file" id='filename' name="filename" onchange="ajaxUpload(this.form,'js/ajaxuploadprofile.php?filename=name&amp;maxSize=2000000&amp;maxW=700&amp;fullPath=images/profilepic/&amp;relPath=../images/profilepic/&amp;colorR=255&amp;colorG=255&amp;colorB=255&amp;maxH=700','upload_area','File Uploading Please Wait...&lt;br /&gt;&lt;img src=\'images/loader_light_blue.gif\' width=\'128\' height=\'15\' border=\'0\' /&gt;','&lt;img src=\'images/error.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' border=\'0\' /&gt; Error in Upload, check settings and path info in source code.'); return false;" />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function uploadphoto()
{
    el = document.getElementById('filename');
    if (el.onclick) 
    {
       el.onclick();
    } 
    else if (el.click) 
    {
       el.click();
    }
//$('#filename').click(); // <-- this also works for me but not my friend
//document.getElementById('filename').click(); // <-- same
}
</script>
```

**Updated Solution**

Recently I found out that `style='display:none'` will have some issue in some browser (or maybe due to the version of the browser). For my case, the version of Chrome is different between mine and my friends and hence it works on my pc but not my friends' pc. However, I am able to solve this problem by replacing `style='display:none'` with `style='visibility:hidden;height:0px'`. the code now is working fine in any pc.

`visibility:hidden` is just hide the view for the content, it will still occupy some space. Hence i added `height:0px` so that it will have same effect like `display:none`.

Comment: What is your friend's machine and browser? Is it an ancient version of  IE by any chance?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your friend's PC, anything would be just guessing. You have to debug the code yourself. If it "does not work", the browser might throw an error message and tell you why.

Comment: Also, it might be due to a user error. Who operates your friend's PC?

Comment: Maybe JavaScript is disabled on your friend's browser?

Comment: Thanks all for replying. Javascript is not disable as other function is working fine. Friend just tested. Work in Chrome but not Chromium. May be is the browser version issue. Is there anyway so that the code is compatible on all browser?

Comment: If that fails in Chromium only most likely it's a browser bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be a browser issue. For an example it might cause problems in IE. If you are using jQuery, you can do as below:

```
$('#button').trigger('click');
```

Or else you can try as below:

```
if( document.createEvent ) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);  
    document.getElementById('button').dispatchEvent(evt);
} else if( document.createEventObject ) { // For IE 8 and below
    var evObj = document.createEventObject();
    document.getElementById('button').fireEvent('onclick', evObj);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the second snippet what jQuery does?

Comment: Yes I know these all are the same behind the scene. But initially I also had the same issue where things work in FF but not in IE. I gave the second option when not using jQuery and before seeing your 1st comment. These two methods helped me.

Comment: This is all I could say as I do not know browser details

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/getelementbyid-form.phtml), you can use the following to create a version of `getElementById` that works even with really old browsers:

```
function getElement (id)
{
    if (document.getElementById)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    else if (document.all)
    {
        return window.document.all[id];
    }
    else if (document.layers)
    {
        return window.document.layers[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which browsers don't support `getElementById`?

Comment: I think we're talking IE4 era, so reeeeeeealy old.

Comment: I'm afraid IE4 isn't a web browser. It's a graphical HTTP client with _some_ scripting abilities :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Next you'll be telling me IE4 users aren't real users, just carbon-based life-forms with the ability to click :-)